# Issue with trying to get an EditText, because of a casting issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working on a gallery type app. The issue that I have at the moment is trying to fetch the typed text within an EditText. The error that I am getting is a casting exception because the code fetches the EditText block from the layout as a TextView block. This only occurs after I swipe, which causes the some of the LinearLayouts imbeded in the second GridLayout to be removed.

The LinearLayouts are put in at runtime into the Gridlayout (with the id product_details), the amount Layouts is calculated according to which picture is pressed on.

This part of the code fetches the current LinearLayouts that are imbeded in the GridLayout:

```
            for (int i = 0; i<codes.size(); i++) {

                //Sets the different elements to te correct texts
                ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                TextView textCode = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                TextView textPrice = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
                EditText editTextQ = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(2);
                EditText editTextC = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(4);

                commentsAddList.add(editTextC.getText().toString());
                quantityAddList.add(editTextQ.getText().toString());
                priceAddList.add(textPrice.getText().toString().substring(1));
                codeAddList.add(textCode.getText().toString());

                productModelAddList.add(new ProductModel());
                productModelAddList.get(i).setCode(codeAddList.get(i));
                if(!quantityAddList.get(i).equals("")) {
                    productModelAddList.get(i).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantityAddList.get(i)));
                }else{
                    productModelAddList.get(i).setQuantity(0);
                }
                productModelAddList.get(i).setComment(commentsAddList.get(i));
                if(!priceAddList.get(i).equals("")) {
                    productModelAddList.get(i).setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceAddList.get(i)));
                }else{
                    productModelAddList.get(i).setPrice(0);
                }
                mRequestPermissions();
                adaptToText.addToList(productModelAddList.get(i));
            }
```

The main picture xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_details"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

    </GridLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

The LinearLayout that is inserted into the GridLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:id="@+id/orderSideLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/productCode"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/productPrice"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="Quantity goes here"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:text="Comments: "
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editTextComments"
        android:hint="Comments here"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure where the casting exception is caused or why exactly it happened. If anyone is able to help, I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be on position 4, you are getting `TextView`

Comment: you can get EditText reference using findviewbyId() too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the view by position getting it by id would be easier.

```
EditText editTextQ = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(2);    
EditText editTextC = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(4);
```

Try this instead:

```
EditText editTextQ = (EditText) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText editTextC = (EditText) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.editTextComments);
```

This will be better because if change the xml, it could change view positions, and find views by id you wouldn't need to change the code.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that! how would I change the id an instanced view through Java?

Comment: I can change id using setId(), but you shouldn't need, because Id is relative to the layout you manipulating, when you use `linearLayout.findViewById` you are asking android for the view with an certain Id that is inside linearLayout, you can have the same id at least in all layout and wouldn't matter, Id just can't repeat it self in the same layout.